# Sybase ASE sever version 16 queries for password and admin users

Tags: passwords, admin, sybase, ase

I have a client who needs to show me the Sybase database Users with Privileged access and the Password configurations set on the database (such as password length and lockout threshold)

I am struggling to find a query that displays the required information because all I can find is how to see password configurations for one user and add admin users

for example: sp_displaylogin joe, will only show the configurations for Joe. How do I view the database server wide password configuration?

Does anyone have a query where we can view a list of users who have privileged access (admin) and see the system-wide password configurations??

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the source code for `sp_displaylogin` and `sp_passwordpolicy`; between these two system procs you should be able to ascertain where all the various details are stored (in system tables) and roll your own code to fit your requirements

Comment: For instance-wide settings you can also run sp_configure 'password'
and sp_passwordpolicy 'list' which will give you the system-level settings but these are still configurable separately per login so markp's answer to check the code in the main login procs is good to check individual settings.